# linq to entities group by with sum on multiple properties

Tags: c#, group-by, linq-to-entities, repository

I've got this at repository level of my application:

```
public Dictionary<TGroupBy, long> GroupBySum<TGroupBy>(Expression<Func<T, long?>> source, Expression<Func<T, TGroupBy>> groupBy)
{
                return dbset
                    .GroupBy(groupBy)
                    .Select(g => new { ent = g.Key, total = g.AsQueryable().Sum(source) })
                    .ToDictionary(d => d.ent, d => d.total);
}
```

I'd like to return something similar but with the sum on multiple properties rather than one. I was thinking returning a collection of type T with some properties populated would probably be the best way of doing it. But is that possible? (I can't do this with linq to objects because the volume of data is too large).

Comment: It is not clear to me what the end result should be: one summation with multiple fields used in the summation or multiple summations, each over one field.

Comment: Multiple summations, each over one field.

Comment: Some sample input/output would help. And how would you change the signature of ` GroupBySum` to support what you want?